# Copy a column from a txt file to a column in Excel file, Python

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am trying to copy the contents of first three columns of a `txt` file to the first three columns of a `Excel` file.

Here is my code:

```
import XlsxWriter
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet1.write('A1', 'Time', bold);worksheet1.write('B1', 'User Value', bold);worksheet1.write('C1','Address', bold);worksheet1.write('D1', 'Serial Number', bold);
items = os.listdir(directory)
for FILE in items:
    if FILE.endswith('file.txt'):
            FileSelection = directory+'/' + FILE
            Array1 = []
            with open(FileSelection, 'r') as f:
                    for line in f:
                        valuesList = line.split('\t')
                        #print valuesList
                        Array1.append(valuesList)

        for j in range(len(Array1)):
            if j == 0:
                continue
            else:
                print Array1[j][0]
                worksheet1.write('A2:D2', Array1[j][0]) #I want to say, copy the columns A to D but start from the second raw
```

However it copies whole the txt array to first column of `Excel` file!

Comment: What do you mean by "column" of a txt file? Are columns separated by tabs?

Comment: Yes they are in form of table(each column is separated by a tab)

Comment: Are you writing to a CSV file (as in your title) or an Excel file (as in your code)?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the 'text file' you want is actually a csv, only with a different delimiter (This is a bit of a confusing convention). You can use the csv module to specify this:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('your file.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
...     for row in reader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
```

There is a similar csv writer module, or do you actually want an excel file?

I have also noticed in your code maybe valueslist should truncate the first 3 columns, as that is what you appear to want...

This is probably why you are getting all of the original file. So change

```
 valuesList = line.split('\t')
```

to

```
valuesList = line.split('\t')[:3]
```